# All pseudo-classes triggering CSS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-class

On what basis do you determine which pseudo-classes are well suited to trigger CSS transitions? Does there exist a list of all such pseudo-classes?

P.S.: I read a bit about it [here](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625816-create-modern-css-animations/5792421-use-pseudo-selectors-to-trigger-css-transitions#/id/r-5792427) which says that there are only some pseudo-classes that are well suited to trigger transitions. I searched for it in [CSS documentation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/) for transitions and MDN Web Docs but could not find the complete list anywhere.

Comment: Pseudo Class and transition are orthogonal features. They are not linked in any way. Transitions apply to properties

Comment: @TemaniAfif In that case, why do some pseudo-classes only trigger CSS transitions? How can one determine whether a pseudo-class will trigger a transition or not?

Comment: @Srishti transitions are triggered on active pseudo class only if transition property is declared in stylesheet for specific element

Comment: @Srishti They are not linked in any way

Comment: @Aleksandar Not all pseudo-classes will trigger a transition, according to the blog written here - https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625816-create-modern-css-animations/5792421-use-pseudo-selectors-to-trigger-css-transitions#/id/r-5792427.

Comment: where in that article it's clearly said *not all pseudo-classes will trigger transition*?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please refer to the first paragraph bookmarked here - https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625816-create-modern-css-animations/5792421-use-pseudo-selectors-to-trigger-css-transitions#/id/r-5793036.

Comment: it's said *not all of them are well suited to transitions* --> this doesn't mean will not trigger them. It's like I told you, it's not well suited to wear something in a particular season (this doesn't mean you cannot or you won't do it). Better read the full Course to understand the reasoning of the author.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif for your valuable input. I've modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Any **user-action** pseudo-class could be used to trigger a CSS transition. There are other types of pseudo-classes which do things like specifically target elements such as children or siblings, whereas in this case we're talking about pseudo-classes that are used to apply styles upon an event happening - namely user interaction.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#user_action_pseudo-classes - I've specifically linked to the section of user-interaction pseudo-classes, although the page in general discusses all types of pseudo-classes.

There aren't any inherent links or relationships between pseudo-classes or transitions, so you should be able to trigger any transition with any *user-action* pseudo-class (given the right rules in your stylesheet).